# How do I set transaction isolation level in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, isolation-level

In laravel 5.5 with MySQL I use `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` to create transactions this way:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    ...
});
```

What is the isolation level for such transaction and is there a way to set it explicitly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default in **SqlLite** is

```
'BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION';
```

The default in **MySQL** is

```
'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED';
```

You can set it yourself by doing something like this

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED');
```

Comment: Specified I'm using laravel 5.5, thank you =)
Is SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL query through pdo compatible with MariaDB or Percona?

Comment: Sorry about that! It will work just fine with MariaDB. Just follow [the MariaDB documentaion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/) and it will work.

Comment: The default isolation level depends on the MySQL version. For 5.7 it is: REPEATABLE READ

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the only question about setting isolation level in Laravel transactions, I will extend previous answer with my piece of code:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::statement('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');

    anyMethodWithConcurrentQueries();
}, 2);
```

- `DB::statement` looks a bit cleaner
- Isolation level **MUST** be set inside `DB::transaction` function, it won't work otherwise (tested on PostgreSQL, may vary)
- Set attempts to `2` to run code again in case of any error

Comment: For MySQL, the isolation level *must* be set outside of the transaction. (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html)